# Filling in blanks based off of criteria of another

Tags: python, dataframe, fillna

So what I am trying to achieve is basically fill in blank rows in a column based off of another columns. so here is a snippet of what my dataframe looks like.

```
Person_Name     State_Abbrev       Bool
george, John    CT                   NO
george, John    PA                   NO
george, John.   NY                   NO
adam, Ross      NY                   YES
adam, Ross      CA                   NO
```

So what I want to do is look at the Person_Name column and say if the bool column says no for each of that specific Person_Name and their are no Yes for that person then make a new column and fill in the column with the word question, but if the Person_Name does have at least one row for that specific person_name that has a yes then dont fill in anything for that person and move on to the next person in my dataframe.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if there's any further clarification you need from my answer. Thanks.

Comment: My bad I actually meant to accept that answer, thank you that was literally exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `groupby` + `transform` + `isin`:

```
df['New'] = df.groupby('Person_Name').Bool\
        .transform(lambda x: 'Question' if ~x.isin(['YES']).any() else '')

df

     Person_Name State_Abbrev Bool       New
0   george, John           CT   NO  Question
1   george, John           PA   NO  Question
2  george, John.           NY   NO  Question
3     adam, Ross           NY  YES          
4     adam, Ross           CA   NO
```